# Vertx AddressResolverOptions setCacheMaxTimeToLive issue

Tags: vert.x, vert.x-webclient

I am working on setting Vertx AddressResolverOptions TTL.
While testing I am seeing an issue where if the Min TTL is not set or set to lesser than Max TTL value, MaxTTL does not take effect.
For testing, I alternate between the host entry with two different ip addresses but the change in IP does not reflect without application restart.
Whereas, if I set min TTL > max TTL, host ip change gets reflected.

Here is the code snippet:

AddressResolverOptions addressResolverOptions = new AddressResolverOptions().setCacheMaxTimeToLive(cacheMaxTimeToLive).setCacheMinTimeToLive(cacheMinTimeToLive);
vertxOptions.setAddressResolverOptions(addressResolverOptions);

and setting Vertx Options
Vertx.vertx(getVertxOptions())

Comment: Could you please report a bug to https://github.com/eclipse-vertx/vert.x/issues

Comment: Here is the bug:https://github.com/eclipse-vertx/vert.x/issues/3395